# Hiding rows based on cell value become unhidden after another row becomes hidden

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide some rows in another worksheet based on the value of cells in another one and I seem to have the VBA code working to a certain degree but it seems that when I change the value to "No" to hide a certain row and then pick "No" for another cell only the rows associated with the second question are hidden and the first set of rows become visible again. See below for the error in context

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If (Target.Row = 12) And (Target.Column = 4) And (Target = "No") Then
Worksheets("Additional Procedures").Rows("13:16").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Worksheets("Additional Procedures").Rows("13:16").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

If (Target.Row = 13) And (Target.Column = 4) And (Target = "No") Then
Worksheets("Additional Procedures").Rows("17:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Worksheets("Additional Procedures").Rows("17:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

So in context, if in the worksheet cell D12 the value is "No" then rows 13:16 get hidden in worksheet "Additional Procedures" **but** then if I were also to have cell D13's value as "No" then rows 13:16 become visible and rows 17:18 become hidden. I'd like for them for rows 13:18 to stay hidden if both cells D12 and D13 have a value of "No"

I also have this code further down which I wrote to hide rows 32:35 only if the values in cells D21:D23 all have the value of "No". I've included this in case this is what is causing the issue:

```
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Range As Variant
Count = 0
Range = Worksheets("Risk Assessment").Range("D21:D23")

For Each Cell In Range
If Cell = "No" Then
Count = Count + 1
End If
Next Cell

If Count = 3 Then
Sheets("Additional Procedures").Select
Worksheets("Additional Procedures").Rows("32:35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Worksheets("Additional Procedures").Rows("32:35").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

Thank you in advance for any advice you guys can provide

Comment: `If (Target.Row = 12) And (Target.Column = 4) And (Target = "No") Then` condition is either true or false and rows are hidden or shown accordingly. Meaning, if Target.Row <> 12 they will be shown. Try a Select statement to stop the `Else` from running if the row <> 12.

Comment: Is `Risk Assessment` the same worksheet as the one containing the first code and when is the second code supposed to run (e.g. when a cell in `D21:D23` has changed?)?

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008 `Risk Assessment` is the same worksheet as the one containing the first code yes, it also contains the second code. `Risk Assessment` has a table of questions and depending on the answer selected on those questions I'd want rows in the worksheet `Additional Procedures` to be hidden. I'd like for the second code to run if and only if all three values in D21:D23 are "No" and if and only if that condition is met then rows 32:35 in `Additional Procedures` should be hidden. I'll give the code you have written below a go - many thanks!

Comment: @Variatus Thanks for this, this didn't occur to me and yet is so obvious. I'll give it a go, thanks for your help!

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have given your code a try and I seem to getting a compile error saying that `Call HideRows` is an sub or function that is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: The 1st code goes into a standard module (in `VBE` use `Insert>Module` and paste the code into the window that opens). The 2nd code goes into a sheet module, in your case in the `Project Explorer` locate the sheet with `Risk Assessment` in parenthesis and double click on it and paste the code. BTW, you don't run anything, this 'works' automatically, anytime you **manually** change a value in those 5 cells. If a formula changes those values it will not work.

Comment: @VBasic2008 you my friend are a life saver, it's astonishing how many mistakes I make when I'm under pressure but I'm slowly getting better thanks to helpful people like yourself. Have a wonderful weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hide Rows of a Range

**Standard Module (e.g. `Module1`)**

```
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Loops through the cells of a given range (SourceRange) and
'               checks their values against a given value (SourceValue).
'               If the values are the same it hides (otherwise it shows)
'               the rows of another given range (HideRows).
' Inputs
'   SourceRange   The range where the value is going to be searched for.
'   SourceValue   The value that is searched for.
'   HideRows      The range whose rows will be hidden or shown.
'   findOneOnly   By default (False), the values of all cells of SourceRange
'                 have to be equal to SourceValue. When set to True, only
'                 one value has to be equal. This has no effect
'                 if SourceRange contains only one cell.
' Remarks:      The comparison is case-sensitive i.e. e.g. A <> a.
'               SourceValue is declared as Variant to be able to hold
'               different data types.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub HideRows(SourceRange As Range, _
             ByVal SourceValue As Variant, _
             HideRows As Range, _
             Optional ByVal findOneOnly As Boolean = False)
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = SourceRange.Value
    
    If Not IsArray(Data) Then GoTo doOne Else GoTo doMulti
        
doOne:
    If Not IsError(Data) Then
        If Data = SourceValue Then GoTo doHideRows Else GoTo doShowRows
    Else
        GoTo doShowRows
    End If
    
doMulti:
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        For j = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            If Not IsError(Data(i, j)) Then
                If Data(i, j) = SourceValue Then
                    If findOneOnly Then GoTo doHideRows
                Else
                    If Not findOneOnly Then GoTo doShowRows
                End If
            Else
                If Not findOneOnly Then GoTo doShowRows
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    If findOneOnly Then GoTo doShowRows Else GoTo doHideRows
    
doHideRows:
    HideRows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Exit Sub

doShowRows:
    HideRows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

**Sheet Module (e.g. `Sheet1`)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const wsName As String = "Additional Procedures"
    Const Criteria As Variant = "No"
    Dim CheckAddress As Variant
    CheckAddress = Array("D12", "D13", "D21:D23")
    Dim HideRowsAddress As Variant
    HideRowsAddress = Array("13:16", "17:18", "32:35")

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim j  As Long
    For j = 0 To UBound(CheckAddress)
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range(CheckAddress(j))) Is Nothing Then
            HideRows Range(CheckAddress(j)), Criteria, _
                ws.Rows(HideRowsAddress(j))
        End If
    Next j

End Sub
```

If only one found `No` in range `D21:D23` should be enough to hide rows `32:35`, use `True`:

```
            HideRows Range(CheckAddress(j)), Criteria, _
                ws.Rows(HideRowsAddress(j)), True
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may do what you want. If not, it should give you new impetus on how to structure the IF conditions. Please try it.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim TgtRows     As String
    
    With Target
        If .Column = 4 Then
            Select Case .Row
                Case 12
                    TgtRows = "13:16"
                Case 13
                    TgtRows = "17:18"
            End Select
            If Len(TgtRows) Then
                ' assuming that Target is on Worksheets("Additional Procedures")
                '                                 comparison is case insensitive
                Rows(TgtRows).EntireRow.Hidden = (StrComp(.Value, "no", vbTextCompare) = 0)
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```